# IntelliJ IDEA Node-Webkit debug is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, node-webkit

I'm setting up node-webkit up on IDEA and have found issue with debugging - breakpoints just don't work.

Here is my code:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="process.mainModule.exports.callback0()">
<script>
    var sup = require('./sup.js')
    document.write(sup.hi())
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*package.json*

```
{
    "main": "index.html",
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "node-main": "node-main.js"
}
```

*sup.js*

```
module.exports = {
    hi: function() {
        return 'hi'; //breakpoint here don't work
    }
}
```

*node-main.js*

```
var i = 0;
exports.callback0 = function () {
    console.log(i + ": " + window.location); //breakpoint here don't work
}
```

**Console output**

```
0: file:///C:/%5CWork%5Cwebkit%5Cwebkitbase/index.html
```

**Html output**

hi

Which means all scripts where executed and problem is within IDEA debug. What could be cause?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in IDEA.

Checked IDEA 13.1.5 and WebStorm 8.0.4.

Both have this issue.

Also there are many other sympthoms of yet raw Node-WebKit support in IDEA/WebStorm:

1) `debugger` statement works but only in sup module (not works in node-main script).

2) index.html debug works but line numbers does't match.

3) step into sup.js from index.html works but it takes to some kind of generated code which looks like:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    module.exports = {
        hi: function() {
            return 'hi'
        }
    }
});
```

There's certain activity on this issue in IDEA/WebStorm bugtracker, but looking on its intensity one could wait for a few month before considering serious use of IDEA node-webkit integration.